# Parse SDK in Android - group by alternatives

Tags: android, parse-platform

My parse DB has 4 models:

1. User
2. League
3. Game
4. GameEvent

User has many leagues.
League has many games.
Game has many gameEvents.

### Table structure:

**League**
[image]

**Game**
[image]

**GameEvent**
[image]

I managed to fetch all the GameEvents of a given league and filter them by:

1. Type = 7 (type = goal)
2. createdAt between the dates the user enters

However, this is not the data I need as I want to find how many goals every player scored in this league between the given dates. (player name is stored as a string in the title field of the GameEvent model).
Basically, I need an SQL style "GROUP BY" query in order to get the count, but "GRUOP BY" is not supported by Parse.

I considered using Parse "cloud coding" with an after_save event, but it won't work because the createdAt range is dynamic.

Is there a way to do it without counting the results in the app itself?